# How can I change the tier of an IoT Central instance?

Tags: azure-iot-central

I tried to change the tier / SKU of my IoT Central instance. However I can't find the option to do so either in the Azure Portal or in IoT Central.

Is it possible to change the SKU of the instance or do I have to create a new instance?

Comment: Yes, you can change the pricing plan for an Azure IoT Central application at any time using UI as well. 
For guidance on how to change plans, please see our [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/howto-faq#how-do-i-change-my-application-pricing-plan)

Comment: @AshokPeddakotla-MSFT No idea how I missed that, thanks! I searched for "change SKU", "change pricing" and "change tier" without success, "change plans" would have worked. I will adapt the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the pricing plan for an Azure IoT Central application via Settings - Application - Pricing. See also the [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/howto-faq#how-do-i-change-my-application-pricing-plan). There is no UI to change the SKU in the Azure Portal.
[image: IoT Central Change Pricing]

It can also be changed through Azure CLI or ARM templates / bicep. The current valid values are `ST0, ST1, ST2` for Standard 0, 1 and 2 respectively.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/iot/central/app?view=azure-cli-latest#az-iot-central-app-update

```
az iot central app update -n my-first-iot-app -g MyResourceGroup --set sku.name=ST1
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.iotcentral/iotapps?tabs=json

```json
{
  "type": "Microsoft.IoTCentral/iotApps",
  "apiVersion": "2021-11-01-preview",
  "name": "string",
  "location": "string",
  "tags": {
    "tagName1": "tagValue1",
    "tagName2": "tagValue2"
  },
  "sku": {
    "name": "string"
  },
  "identity": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "string",
    "networkRuleSets": {
      "applyToDevices": "bool",
      "applyToIoTCentral": "bool",
      "defaultAction": "string",
      "ipRules": [
        {
          "filterName": "string",
          "ipMask": "string"
        }
      ]
    },
    "publicNetworkAccess": "string",
    "subdomain": "string",
    "template": "string"
  }
}
```